# 定義されているメソッドのソースコードをpryなどで確認する方法

Tags: ruby, pry

Rubyだと、例えば`Method.source_location`を利用することによって、そのメソッドが定義されているファイルパスと行数を確認できるかと思います。

しかし、もう少し踏み込んで、定義場所だけではなく、そのメソッドの実際の挙動、つまりソースコード自体もその場で確認したいという場合、`pry`などで実際に定義されたときのソースを閲覧する方法というものはあったりするのでしょうか?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

pryでshow-sourceを利用すれば可能だと思います。

```
[1] pry(main)> show-source Pry

From: /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/pry_instance.rb @ line 24:
Class name: Pry
Number of monkeypatches: 6. Use the `-a` option to display all available monkeypatches
Number of lines: 641

class Pry
  attr_accessor :binding_stack

:q

[2] pry(main)> show-method pry

From: /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/core_extensions.rb @ line 41:
Owner: Object
Visibility: public
Number of lines: 7

def pry(object=nil, hash={})
  if object.nil? || Hash === object
    Pry.start(self, object || {})
  else
    Pry.start(object, hash)
  end
end
```

また、`$`が別名として定義されているので、そちらを使う事もできます

```
[3] pry(main)> require 'rexml/document'
=> true
[4] pry(main)> $ REXML::Document

From: /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rexml/document.rb @ line 20:
Class name: REXML::Document
Number of lines: 226

class Document < Element
  # A convenient default XML declaration.  If you want an XML declaration,
  # the easiest way to add one is mydoc << Document::DECLARATION
  # +DEPRECATED+
```